# Is the sequence $( d(x_{n},y_{n}))$ convergent if $X = \mathbb{R}$ with standard topology.

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $ ( x_{n} )$ , $ ( y_{n} )$ convergent sequences in $X$. Is the sequence $( d(x_{n},y_{n}))$ convergent if $X = \mathbb{R}$ with standard topology.

I am having trouble showing that it is convergent because it seems to me like the metric $d$ could be anything. Or does it have to be the absolute value on $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: My guess is that you meant “sequence”, not “series”.

Comment: Yes, sorry I edited it.

Comment: The absolute value metric generates the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$, so I guess this is what you need here.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x, y$ be the respective limits. Then
$$d(x_n, y_n) \leq d(x, x_n) +d(x, y) +d(y, y_n) $$
and
$$d(x, y) \leq d(x, x_n) +d(x_n, y_n) +d(y, y_n) $$
so
$$d(x_n, y_n) \geq d(x, y) - d(x, x_n) - d(y, y_n) $$
Since $d(x, x_n) \to 0$ and $d(y, y_n) \to 0$, these bounds imply that $d(x_n, y_n) \to d(x, y) $.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it always converges, no matter what is the metric that you are working with. In fact, if $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=x$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=y$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}d(x_n,y_n)=d(x,y)$.

Comment: Can you prove that?

Comment: I could, but Matt Samuel did just that.